# Post an array using PHP socket

Tags: php, sockets

HI,

I want to send post data using PHP Soket.

How can I Post?

E.g   `$postData = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');`

I want to send $postData from "index.php" to "myweb.php" page using PHP Socket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to serialize the data somehow. You could use [serialize()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) between PHP scripts; however, if you think the data will be used by others, JSON might be preferred: [json_encode()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
 function http_request($request_url, $type='get', $data=array()) {
    $url   = parse_url($request_url);
    $host  = $url['host'];
    $path  = $url['path'];
    $query = $url['query'];
    $path .= $query ? '?'. $query : '';

    $parameter = $sep = '';
    if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $parameter .= $sep . urlencode($key) .'='. urlencode($value);
            $sep = '&';
        }
    }
    if (strtolower($type) == 'get') {
        $path .= $parameter;
        $out  = "GET {$path} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept-Language: zh-cn\r\n";
        $out .= "User-Agent: {$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: {$host}\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    } else {
        $out  = "POST {$path} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept-Language: zh-cn\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $out .= "User-Agent: {$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: {$host}\r\n";
        $out .= 'Content-Length: '.strlen($parameter)."\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        $out .= $parameter;
    }
    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp) {
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not trying to just create an AJAX request? Sockets are created on the server side so while it's not so very unusual to create a socket on a web page it is strange to have it turn around and establish an HTTP connection to a local resource.

Comment: NO, I am not making an ajax request. I am just trying to call simply HTTP request. Can I pass the data with GET ?

Comment: I got the       answer.                                                       By using HTTP_Request and adapter as socket we can post data to destination. Thanks !