# Relaying $_POST, adding authentication to external page without cURL

Tags: php

I am attempting to relay a form to an external site for it to be handled and sorted into a database, but I need to add Basic Authentication to the HTTP header. I do not know much about HTTP headers and have attempted to do so, but I'm confused about how to add the $_POST payload and whether or not I have done the Authorization correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
$user = "snip";
$pass = "snip";

$header = "POST /WebServices/Post/?various_get=variables HTTP/1.1\n".
          "Host:snipped.domain\n".
          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n".
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n".
          "User-Agent: PHP-Code\n".
          "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($user.':'.$pass)."\n".
          "Connection: close\n";

//Print post?

header('location:complete.html');
?>
```

Mainly, I have to send the new header to an external page, and then redirect the user elsewheres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without CURL, the only other way I know of is to [open a socket](https://www.php.net/function.fsockopen) and post it manually.

[Post an array using PHP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553594/post-an-array-using-php-socket)

Comment: I understand that you /can/ do this with CURL, but I'm asking about how to do it without it.